# controller does not added in asp net core , simplcommerce project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoxJn.png)In simplcommerce open source, use of asp net core in controller is not added in project specified runtimeconfig.json does not exist issue.

Comment: I may suggest you post your code, not image.

Comment: In not coding our project only added controller but not added runtimeconfig.json does not exist issue. please to any solution thanks..

Comment: The specified runtimeconfig.json [D:\inforgrowth-sourcecode\src\Modules\SimplCommerce.Module.ActivityLog\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\SimplCommerce.Module.ActivityLog.runtimeconfig.json] does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Does this error is thrown when you tried to add new controller?